# Django/Wagtail/taggit - Getting model specific tag list

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail, django-taggit

I have seen this:

[Generating a unique list of Django-Taggit Tags in Wagtail;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061564/generating-a-unique-list-of-django-taggit-tags-in-wagtail)

and the solutions there have generated a list of all stored tags, i.e. image, document, etc tags.

I am trying to accomplish a similar goal. On a News Index Page, have a dropdown of the News Page Tags.

I can't seem to get a list of tags that are only News Page Tags, currently this gives me a list of all tags in my site, including image and document tags.

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase, Tag
from core.models import Page

class NewsPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('NewsPage', related_name='tagged_items')


class NewsPage(Page):
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=NewsPageTag, blank=True)


class NewsIndexPage(Page):

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all().distinct('taggit_taggeditem_items__tag')
        return TemplateResponse(
            request,
            self.get_template(request, *args, **kwargs),
            context
        )
```

I have also tried:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
# ...
def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    news_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(NewsPage)
    context['tags'] = Tag.objects.filter(
        taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=news_content_type
    )
    return TemplateResponse(
        request,
        self.get_template(request, *args, **kwargs),
        context
    )
```

which assigns `context['tags']` an empty set

My template:

```
{% if tags.all.count %}
    {% for tag in tags.all %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="?tag={{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

HELP! This feels like it shouldn't be so complicated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could copy how this is achieved in the new [Wagtail Bakery Demo application](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo) which is a great reference.

Essentially just getting all the child pages and then getting their tags, using `set` to ensure that they are unique objects.

First add a method to your `NewsIndexPage` that will help you get these tags in a consistent way.

[See: `models.py`](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/blog/models.py#L212-L219)

```
class NewsIndexPage(Page):

    # Returns the list of Tags for all child posts of this BlogPage.
    def get_child_tags(self):
        tags = []
        news_pages = NewsPage.objects.live().descendant_of(self);
        for page in news_pages:
            # Not tags.append() because we don't want a list of lists
            tags += page.get_tags
        tags = sorted(set(tags))
        return tags
```

Because you have a method on your NewsPageIndex model, you do not need o override the `serve` method, you can get the tags directly in your template like this.

```
    {% if page.get_child_tags %}
        {% for tag in page.get_child_tags %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?tag={{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

See a similar template approach in the Wagtail Bakery Demo's [`blog_index_page.html`](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html#L16-L22)

Note: You can still add to the context by doing something like this in the `serve` method:

```
context['tags'] = self.get_child_tags()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great and the Wagtail Bakery Demo is very helpful.